# android - switch case return value for if statement

Tags: java, android

In my app I have an image which is randomly picked. The image appears on the screen and the user can slide it to the side. Everytime it is a image `a`, the counter should count, but it doesn't. Is the return value of my int getMyRandomResId wrong in the condition, or where is the fault?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private ImageView imageView;
    public int sco = 0;
    float x1, x2;
    float y1, y2;
    final Random rand = new Random();    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        score.setText(String.valueOf(sco));
    }

    int getMyRandomResId()
    {
        int imag = rand.nextInt(4);

        switch (imag)
        {
            case 0:
                return R.drawable.a;
            case 1:
                return R.drawable.b;
            case 2:
                return R.drawable.c;
            default:
                return R.drawable.d;
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
    {
        final ViewPropertyAnimator animator = imageView.animate();

        switch (touchevent.getAction())
        {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {

            x1 = touchevent.getX();
            y1 = touchevent.getY();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {

            x2 = touchevent.getX();
            y2 = touchevent.getY();

            //if left to right sweep event on screen
            if (x1 < x2 && (x2 - x1) >= (y1 - y2) && (x2 - x1) >= (y2 - y1))
            {

                if(getMyRandomResId() == R.drawable.a)
                {
                    sco++;
                    score.setText(String.valueOf(sco));
                }

                animationRunning = true;
                animator.translationX((imageView.getWidth()))
                .setDuration(250)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                    {


                        imageView.setTranslationX(0);
                        imageView.setImageResource(getMyRandomResId());
                        animationRunning = false;

                    }
                })
                .start();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I confused myself in the answer as @StefMa pointed me, i gotta ask you a thing here: with debugger, did you try checking if the if condition is reached? try istantiating the result of your getMyRandomId in a variable and with debugger check the value of it

Comment: I guess you code is correct. But unfortunately (because of the random int) you haven't ever reached the point. I've created a Test setup and it is green. That means everything is correct... See https://git.io/v1Hrw

Comment: @StefMa So do you know why it doesn't work, then?

Comment: @mohanrathour you are wrong. He compare an `int`. Not an `Integer`...

Comment: @StefMa Why doesn't it reach the point?

Comment: See my answer below...

Comment: I did. Is the way I put the `sco` out right or can't it work like that?

Comment: @StefMa I play around a little with the code, you're code below works, you said?

Comment: Yes, my code work

Answer (score 4):

Each time you create `Random rand = new Random();` it starts from the same point. Here is a quote from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html)

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers.

You should create an instance of `Random` class only once. For example, like this:

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final Random random = new Random();
    ...`

Comment: Am I not creating the random object once?

Comment: Try creating it once per class, let's say next to `public int sco = 0;` you put `final Random rand = new Random();`

Comment: @JoeS: You are creating it every time you call `getMyRandomResId()`. You should instead declare the `Random` in the class as a member variable.

Comment: I tried it, it chooses an image, but when image a is selected, it still doesn't count so far

Answer (score 1):

I guess you miss something here.
I've tested your posted code and it works like a charm.
`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int sco = 0;

    float x1, x2;

    float y1, y2;

    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        final ViewPropertyAnimator animator = imageView.animate();

        switch (touchevent.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                x1 = touchevent.getX();
                y1 = touchevent.getY();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                x2 = touchevent.getX();
                y2 = touchevent.getY();

                //if left to right sweep event on screen
                if (x1 < x2 && (x2 - x1) >= (y1 - y2) && (x2 - x1) >= (y2 - y1)) {

                    final int randomResId = getMyRandomResId();
                    Log.e("ResId: ", String.valueOf(randomResId));
                    if (randomResId == R.drawable.ic_assignment_late_black_24dp) {
                        sco++;
                        Log.e("NewScoId", String.valueOf(sco));
                    }

                    animator.translationX((imageView.getWidth()))
                            .setDuration(250)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                                    imageView.setTranslationX(0);
                                    imageView.setImageResource(randomResId);

                                }
                            })
                            .start();
                }

            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x);
    }

    int getMyRandomResId() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int imag = rand.nextInt(4);

        switch (imag) {
            case 0:
                return R.drawable.ic_assignment_late_black_24dp;
            case 1:
                return R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp;
            case 2:
                return R.drawable.ic_battery_charging_30_black_24dp;
            default:
                return R.drawable.ic_exposure_neg_2_black_24dp;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And used random images created with the create Vector asset wizzard.
My LogCat (while swiping) looks like that:

```
 E/ResId:: 2130837590
 E/ResId:: 2130837590
 E/ResId:: 2130837589
 E/ResId:: 2130837588
 E/NewScoId: 1
 E/ResId:: 2130837587
 E/ResId:: 2130837590
 E/ResId:: 2130837588
 E/NewScoId: 2
 E/ResId:: 2130837587
 E/ResId:: 2130837589
 E/ResId:: 2130837588
 E/NewScoId: 3
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

getMyRandomResId() this method is working fine and although the suggestion of foxanna is also better here are some changes that i have done i have tested this and worked for me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private ImageView imageView;
    public int sco = 0;
    float x1, x2;
    float y1, y2;
    Random rand;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        score.setText(String.valueOf(sco));
        rand = new Random();
    }

int getMyRandomResId()
{
    int imag = rand.nextInt(4);

    switch (imag)
    {
        case 0:
            sco++;
            return R.drawable.a;
        case 1:
            return R.drawable.b;
        case 2:
            return R.drawable.c;
        default:
            return R.drawable.d;
    }
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
{
    final ViewPropertyAnimator animator = imageView.animate();

    switch (touchevent.getAction())
    {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    {

        x1 = touchevent.getX();
        y1 = touchevent.getY();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    {

        x2 = touchevent.getX();
        y2 = touchevent.getY();

        //if left to right sweep event on screen
        if (x1 < x2 && (x2 - x1) >= (y1 - y2) && (x2 - x1) >= (y2 - y1))
        {

            if(getMyRandomResId() == R.drawable.a)
            {
                score.setText(String.valueOf(sco));
            }

            animationRunning = true;
            animator.translationX((imageView.getWidth()))
            .setDuration(250)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                {


                    imageView.setTranslationX(0);
                    imageView.setImageResource(getMyRandomResId());
                    animationRunning = false;

                }
            })
            .start();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps.